# JUNK Character in text pad for foreign language in HADOOP mapreduce

Tags: java, hadoop, utf-8, mapreduce

I have and application where i have to read HBase and write into files in text format .
Everything work fine but requirement from the client is that they need to have files in UTF-8-BOM encoding format .
I have not mentioned any encoding format explicitly and by default it comes as UTF-8 format .

Is there anyway to to write into the files in UTF-8-BOM format .

Please consider that i am doing all these in mapreduce .

I have tried with below changes in the driver code but then also it comes out as UTF-8 format .

```
hbaseConf.set("mapreduce.child.java.opts", "-Xmx6553m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8-BOM");
```

Thanks in advance ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No extra encoding is required to mention in the config .
I have solved it by Appending "\uFEFF" in the first row and it worked fine for me .No extra character in the output file also .All good now